# Custom URL Facebook App

Tags: facebook

How can I get a custom URL for a Facebook Application (not a Page, an Application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than your canvas url

> http:// apps.facebook.com/your_app/

No I do not think so. The only thing shorter I can think of is fb.me

> http:// apps.fb.me/your_app/